# I am not able to display graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to print a logistic differential equation and I'm pretty sure the equation is written correctly but my graph doesn't display anything.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def eq(con,x):
    return con*x*(1-x)

xList = np.linspace(0,4, num=1000)
con = 2.6
x= .4

for num in range(len(xList)-1):
    plt.plot(xList[num], eq(con,x))
    x=eq(con,x)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.title("Logistic Differential Equation")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get nothing in your plot because you are plotting points.

In plt you need to have x array and y array (that have the same length) in order to make a plot.

If you want to do exactly what you are doing I suggest to do like this:

```
import matplotlyb.pyplot as plt # just plt is sufficent 
import numpy as np
def eq(con,x):
    return con*x*(1-x)

xList = np.linspace(0,4, num=1000)
con = 2.6
x= .4

y = np.zeros(len(xList)) # initialize an array with the same lenght as xList
for num in range(len(xList)-1):
    y[num] = eq(con,x)
    x=eq(con,x)

plt.figure() # A good habit is always to use figures in plt 
plt.plot(xList, y) # 2 arrays of the same lenght
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.title("Logistic Differential Equation")

plt.show() # now you should get somthing here
```

I hope that this helps you ^^